# How to get current or previous route?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have custom tabBarButtonComponent `<AddButton/>` inside bottom tab navigator. When user tap on this button, new screen will be opened based on which tab is currently selected. So I want to know which screen is currently open.

```
const ContentNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Photo: {
      screen: Photo,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <BottomIcon name="photo" color={tintColor}/>
        )
      })
    },
    Audio: {
      screen: Audio,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <BottomIcon name="audio" color={tintColor}/>
        )
      })
    },
    Adding: {
      screen: () => null,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        tabBarButtonComponent: () => (
          <AddButton navigation={navigation}/>
        )
      })
    },
    Video: {
      screen: Video,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <BottomIcon name="video" color={tintColor}/>
        )
      })
    },
    Text: {
      screen: Text,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <BottomIcon name="text" color={tintColor}/>
        )
      })
    }
  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: '#fff',
      inactiveTintColor: '#000',
    }
  }
)
```

I tried to pass navigation props to `<AddButton/>`, navigation routeName is giving 'Adding'.
When custom button clicked, how would I get current tab name?

Comment: Do your AddButton class have an event like onPress? If yes, you may try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the screen you are currently in doing

```
 this.props.navigation.state.params.routeName
```

You will have the current tab you are into. If you need to get the lastScreen you will have to pass it like a param in your `<AddButton\>`, for example:

```
<Button onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('tabName',{lastScreen: this.props.navigation.state.params.routeName})}
```

And when you need to navigate back it becomes:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(this.props.navigation.state.params.lastScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for this specific usage of navigation, you can use redux for saving current tab name. so in the AddButton component
you can access previous tab name and take an action based on your business.